# Use SELECT inside an IF statement

Tags: oracle, if-statement

I want a query like this:

```
 if ((select closedatetime from tbl_eventschedularmaster where eventid=p_EventId)> sysdate)
 then
     update tbL_ANSWERMASTER set AnsText=p_AnsText
      where AnsId=p_checkduplicate RETURNING AnsId INTO p_ReturnVal;
else 
      RETURNING 0 INTO p_ReturnVal;
 end if
```

but it is not working

Comment: What is the problem with that code?

Comment: Error(29,15): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT" when expecting one of the following:     ( - + case mod new not null <an identifier>    <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable>    continue avg count current exists max min prior sql stddev    sum variance execute forall merge time timestamp interval    date <a string literal with character set specification>    <a number> <a single-quoted SQL string> pipe    <an alternatively-quoted string literal with character set specification>    <an alternat

Comment: in if condition where i insert closedatetime to sysdate

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to re-write that as

```
select closedatetime
  into dtClosedDateTime
  from tbl_eventschedularmaster
  where eventid = p_EventId;

if dtClosedDateTime > sysdate then
  update tbL_ANSWERMASTER
    set AnsText=p_AnsText
    where AnsId=p_checkduplicate
    RETURNING AnsId INTO p_ReturnVal;
else 
  p_ReturnVal := 0;
end if;
```

Share and enjoy.